# How to get a list of members and their Active assignment role in Azure AD?

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory

I would like to do a validation of members who have an "Active assignment" role in Azure AD. Is there a way to know if the role was granted by a group or directly? How could I get the information into my script? Thank you for your help

```
connect-azuread

$roles = Get-AzureADDirectoryRole | select objectid, displayname


ForEach($role in $roles){

Get-AzureADDirectoryRoleMember -ObjectId $role.ObjectId | select @{n="Azure role";e={$role.DisplayName}}, displayname

}
```

Comment: nvm, i got what i needed. I just added select objecttype at the end. If you find something easier, will be great too :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You found the easiest solution using powershell.I check with Ms graph it is bit difficult than powershell. I also removed one of the statement from your code which is not required .

**I tested in my environment working fine for me.**

```
connect-azuread

$roles = Get-AzureADDirectoryRole


ForEach($role in $roles){

Get-AzureADDirectoryRoleMember -ObjectId $role.ObjectId | select @{n="Azure role";e={$role.DisplayName}}, displayname

}
```

output:
[image]